# Cabecera y pie de tabla inmovilizados al hacer scroll

Tags: html, css

Alguien podría ayudarme como hacer que la cabecera y el pie de la tabla se quede inmovilizada con css o javascript al hacer scroll?

```css
<style>
 table.tablaordenada {
  font-family:arial;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
  font-size: 8pt;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;

 }

 table.tablaordenada thead tr th, table.tablaordenada tfoot tr th {
  background-color: #e6EEEE;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  font-size: 8pt;
  padding: 4px;
 }


 table.tablaordenada thead tr .header {
  background-image: url(bg.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center right;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
 }

 table.tablaordenada tbody td {
  color: #3D3D3D;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  vertical-align: top;
 }

 table.tablaordenada tbody tr.odd td {
  background-color:#F0F0F6;
 }

 table.tablaordenada thead tr .headerSortUp {
  background-image: url(asc.gif);
 }

 table.tablaordenada thead tr .headerSortDown {
  background-image: url(desc.gif);
 }

 table.tablaordenada thead tr .headerSortDown, table.tablaordenada thead tr .headerSortUp {
  background-color: #8dbdd8;
 }
</style>
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>


        <table class="tablaordenada " border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="2"><a href=""></a>&nbsp;#</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">CIA</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Ambulatorio</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Hospitalario</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Total</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-transform: uppercase;"> Cuentas </td>
                    <th style="text-transform: uppercase;"> Consumo </td>
                    <th style="text-transform: uppercase;"> Cuentas </td>
                    <th style="text-transform: uppercase;"> Consumo </td>
                    <th style="text-transform: uppercase;"> Cuentas </td>
                    <th style="text-transform: uppercase;"> Consumo </td>
                </tr> 
            </thead>
            <tbody>


                <tr>
                    <td align="center">1</td>
                    <td>empresa</td>
                    <td align="right">5452</td>
                    <td align="right">545212</td>
                    <td align="right">5424121</td>
                    <td align="right">4523131</td>
                    <td align="right">5421</td>
                    <td align="right">541512</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">1</td>
                    <td>empresa</td>
                    <td align="right">5452</td>
                    <td align="right">545212</td>
                    <td align="right">5424121</td>
                    <td align="right">4523131</td>
                    <td align="right">5421</td>
                    <td align="right">541512</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">1</td>
                    <td>empresa</td>
                    <td align="right">5452</td>
                    <td align="right">545212</td>
                    <td align="right">5424121</td>
                    <td align="right">4523131</td>
                    <td align="right">5421</td>
                    <td align="right">541512</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">1</td>
                    <td>empresa</td>
                    <td align="right">5452</td>
                    <td align="right">545212</td>
                    <td align="right">5424121</td>
                    <td align="right">4523131</td>
                    <td align="right">5421</td>
                    <td align="right">541512</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">1</td>
                    <td>empresa</td>
                    <td align="right">5452</td>
                    <td align="right">545212</td>
                    <td align="right">5424121</td>
                    <td align="right">4523131</td>
                    <td align="right">5421</td>
                    <td align="right">541512</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">1</td>
                    <td>empresa</td>
                    <td align="right">5452</td>
                    <td align="right">545212</td>
                    <td align="right">5424121</td>
                    <td align="right">4523131</td>
                    <td align="right">5421</td>
                    <td align="right">541512</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">1</td>
                    <td>empresa</td>
                    <td align="right">5452</td>
                    <td align="right">545212</td>
                    <td align="right">5424121</td>
                    <td align="right">4523131</td>
                    <td align="right">5421</td>
                    <td align="right">541512</td>
                </tr>

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" style="text-transform: uppercase;"> Total</th>
                    <th align="right">6532</th>
                    <th align="right">121</th>
                    <th align="right">54213</th>
                    <th align="right">545212</th>
                    <th align="right">21212</th>
                    <th align="right">5452121</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </tbody>
    </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solo pon en tus estilos

```
thead
{
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: En realidad seria bueno primero probar el codigo; nada mas aplicar `position: fixed` destruye el estilo de la tabla

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner en el css:

**EDITADO**

```
table.tablaordenada thead{
  position: fixed;
}
```

Esto hace q al scrollear en al pagina, quede el item "pegado" arriba.

Comment: puse el codigo en el css, pero no me funciona amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Depende del contexto de la página que estés trabajando, pero si solo tienes la tabla en la página agrega el siguiente css:

```
table.tablaordenada thead{
   position: fixed;
   top:0px; /* Este lo modificas dependiendo de que altura de la pantalla quieres que se fije el contenedor*/
   left:0px;  /* Estos dos son para centrar el contenedor*/
   right:0px;
}
```